# invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, tensorflow, decision-trees

I ran this code and this doesn't work, I'm using python 3 btw, I have checked the syntax a million times. I have installed all the necessary packages and all of them are up to date, here is the code I ran:

```
from sklearn import tree
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]]
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print(clf.predict([[150, 0]]))
```

Here is the console error message (I don't know what it's exactly called, please tell me if you know):

```
pydev debugger: starting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 111, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 36, in debug
    run(address, filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\_main.py", line 47, in run_file
    run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\_main.py", line 98, in _run
    _pydevd.main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1628, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1035, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\Sanjay\Documents\python files\SLNforVt\VisualTest\VisualTest.py", line 6
    print(clf.predict([[150, 0]]))
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

I am using Visual Studios here, I do not know if that affects this program in anyway but I also tried it using the python idle. Other Python programs I write work fine on Visual Studios without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your text has some characters that the editor does not show.  Using an online UTF-8 encoder, you can see that the end of the line has:

```
\x29\xef\xbb\xbf\x0a
```

When it should simply be a close paren and a new line like:

```
\x29\x0a
```

You need to delete the offended characters.  Best way to handle these situations, is to select an area of the text on either side of the compiler complaint and delete it all as a block and then retype the text.

After the cleanup your code produces:

```
[1]
```

PS: That error output is called a stack trace, and it was exactly right, there was an invalid character present at the location indicated.

Comment: I just re-wrote the code, I had just pasted it from a comment on youtube, that must be the problem, it works now

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this problem in sublime text 3 after getting a file from a coworker.

I solved the problem by reopening the file with a different encoding (from `utf-8` to `western (iso 8859-15)`).

Here's the code in `utf-8`:

[image]

And here's the code in `iso 8859-15`:

[image]

I deleted all these strange chars, and I used the `save with encoding` feature to save my file.